# Webview cannot go back with local html

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview that load up a URL from internet, but when there is no connectivity (onReceiedError) it loads up a locally saved html document in assets folder.

but when I press back button on that particular activity (which loads up the local HTML) it doesn't go back to the previous activity instead tries to refresh the page.. It is only after 4-5 Back presses it goes back.

here is my code.

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{    
         @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,                
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
             mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);  
                mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false); 
                mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);   
             mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/offline.html"); 
         }


        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
        {
            webview.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((KeyCode)== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && mWebView.canGoBack())   
        {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(KeyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        this.finish();
        overridePendingTransition  (0, R.anim.right_slide_out);
        return;
    }
    }
```

Works fine with the normal webpage to load from Internet.

Answer (score 0):

coz in onReceivedError you change the url . so there will be no goback event

you have to just show toast message and delete `mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/offline.html");`